# reading a line into three variables

Tags: c

I want to read lines from a text file and store the information in three variables. For example, if the line from a file is

```
A Tale of Two Cities  Charles Dickens 1859
```

I want to store this into two char arrays and one int variable. So, I want to extract the following information from the line. There is no delimiter like comma or hyphen in the line.

```
title[] = "A Tale of Two Cities"
author[] = "Charles Dickens"
year = 1859
```

How can this be done in `C`? Problem is that `title` could have variable number of words in it. Same for the `author`. If there was fixed number of words in either of them, then problem is easy. So, what is the desirable solution here ?

Comment: If you can add commas (`,`) between the fields it will enable you to parse multiple word values.

Comment: Looks to me like there is 2 spaces between the title and author?  If that is the case, you can search for 2 spaces.  Then, the last field can just be the last 4 bytes.

Comment: You can't ask random people on the Internet what file format a very local file on your computer has. You tell us. It looks like there are maybe 2 spaces between the title and author? Or maybe a tab? You tell us... It might very well be that the file format doesn't make sense to begin with.

Comment: Actually, I have come up with this problem on my own. If we do not know how many spaces are between title and author, or between author and year, is the problem too  hard ?

Comment: You are going to read the entire line into memory and then analyze it. This is not a task for any of the `scanf()` family of functions.  They are all too blasé about ignoring spaces.

Comment: If there is no unambiguous delimiter between the first field and the second field, then there is no way for the program to reliably split the two fields in the correct place. The only thing you could maybe do is to use artificial intelligence to guess where one field ends and the next field starts. However, if you do have an unambiguous delimiter, such as two spaces in a row, then the problem would be easy to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these files have a predefined file format, your best bet is to find out what that format is; only then will you be able to even begin writing a program that reads the files.

If, on the other hand, these files are something you personally made up, then the format is completely up to you; but whatever format you choose, you have to ensure that each file conforms to it. After you have decided this format, you can begin to design a parser that reads the files.

If you do not know in advance the number of spaces between fields, then you have to use a delimiter, which is a symbol that definitively marks the end of that field. For example:

`A Tale of Two Cities  Charles Dickens 1859`

Could be:

`A Tale of Two Cities      |Charles Dickens| 1859|`

Where the pipe symbol is the delimiter. Then, you can separate each field by looking for the pipe, ignoring leading and trailing spaces afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that there are *two* spaces between the title and the author is a delimiter itself. Split on that:

```
// Find the separation between title and author
char * sep1 = strstr( line, "  " );
if (!sep1) fooey();

// Find the separation between the author and the year
char * sep2 = strrchr( sep1+2, ' ' );
if (!sep2) fooey();

// Parse out the data
*sep1 = *sep2 = '\0';
strcpy( title, line );
strcpy( author, sep1+2 );
year = strotol( sep2+1, NULL );
```